# Need a quick crash course in WPF

Tags: wpf

So I am interviewing for a job. In the initial interview, they asked lots of tech questions, and I answered enough of them correctly that they wanted to move on to the next stage.  The next stage is they sent me a Visual Studio solution with a set of instructions of modifications and bug fixes.

Here's the catch: It's a WPF solution.  During the first interview, they never asked about WPF.  If they had, I would have told them that I don't have ANY experience in it.

So my immediate problem/question is this:

In the solution there is a file called ShellWindow.xaml and it's accompanying ShellWindoe.xaml.cs.  I've been able to figure out enough to learn that ShellWindow.xaml is (I think) the UI file.  At least, that's what it looks like.  It already has lots of what look like UI elements in it.

```
<Grid>...
    <DoclPanel>...
        <StackPanel>...
            <TextBlock>...
```

What I can't figure out is how to execute this file.  When I right click on it, there is no "Set as default startup" option.  When I try to run the entire solution in debug, I am told, "In order to debug this project, add an executable project to the solution...."

I've thought about calling them back and saying, "Sorry guys, I don't know WPF.  Can I just do this in MVC instead?"  But I'd like to at least take a crack at this.

Can anyone help me out with this first step of figuring out how to at least interact with the UI elements they already have in place?

Thanks!

Comment: EBen  if youdid get this one little project figured out,  don't you think they'd realize pretty quickly you couldn't work in it after hiring? Best to fess up now I think and then pick up some detailed books. ..

Comment: Oh I fully intend to tell them.  And, the amount of time it takes me to complete this little exercise will also be a pretty big clue!

Comment: "In order to debug this project, add an executable project to the solution" means that the project you set as default startup is not executable bug Library project. You can change it in project settings.

Comment: If your project is test one (not commertial), you could share it and we could help you much more quickly. Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah that's a good question.  I thought about that too, but I'm not sure of the legal issues.

Comment: VMaleev - your tip above was right on.  There is a a .Wpf project in the solution, and I was able to set that to be the startup project.  Now, when I hit f5, there is a UI window that opens.

Comment: I will post other specific questions as I have them, with code samples.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: I've posted an answer, please feel free to ask more questions on WPF, we will try to help you as possible

Comment: VMaleev - thank you so much!  Can we continue this conversation in Chat?  Also, what would be the best way to share the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In order to debug this project, add an executable project to the solution" means that the project you set as default startup is not executable bug Library project. You can change it in project settings.

Answer (score -2):

No offense intended, but if you've never worked in WPF before, you'll likely get tossed out of the interview in under 5 minutes :). WPF has a ton of concepts that don't exist in any other framework, especially when you throw MVVM into the mix. Had a cocky co-worker who thought he could BS his way through a WPF interview and he got tossed out after 1 or 2 questions :). When he told me the questions he was asked and the answers he gave, I told him I would have tossed him out too because they were not even in the ballpark. Not something you can crash course in a weekend either IMO. It would probably take 3 to 6 months of working in it daily to pick up all the new concepts I would think. *VERY* steep learning curve for WPF & MVVM.

Comment: Ya... you said you wanted to "take a crack at it" :). Just was pointing out that looking at some sample code for an hour isn't going to get you through a WPF interview because of all the new concepts :). There's no such thing a "quick crash course in WPF" (your title).

Comment: So I guess you missed the part where I said the technical interview already happened, and they never asked about MVP.